# How to Configure OpenEMS(www.openems.io)?

Tags: configuration, architecture, project, software-design

-What is OpenEMS?
-What backend DB does OPenEMS require?
-To do the customization on the OpenEMS, is it to be done on the Edge or in UI?
-What changes can be done on the OpenEMS UI?
-Do we have a web portal to view and monitor the device connected with OpenEMS?
-How to configure and run the OpenEMS platform?
-How to Deploy OpenEMS Edge & UI?
-What type of server is needed to host the OpenEMS platform?
-What kind of technical expertise is needed to develop/customise the platform?

Answer (score 1):

- What is OpenEMS?
- How to configure and run the OpenEMS platform?  How
- to Deploy OpenEMS Edge & UI?

For those 3 question, see details on the main [site](https://openems.github.io/openems.io/openems/latest/introduction.html):

- To do the customization on the OpenEMS, is it to be done on the Edge or in UI?

Both.

- What changes can be done on the OpenEMS UI?

The question is too vague. The project is opensource; in theory, everything can be changed.

Do we have a web portal to view and monitor the device connected with OpenEMS?

Yes, see the content here: https://openems.github.io/openems.io/openems/latest/gettingstarted.html#_run_openems_ui

- What type of server is needed to host the OpenEMS platform?

Works on Linux and Windows currently

- What kind of technical expertise is needed to develop/customise the platform?

Knowledge of Java is a good start for Edge and Backend, Javascript is needed for UI.